# JavaFX TextArea & TextField display different colors

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, textfield, styling

On my screen I want to have a TextArea and a TextField, whose background-colors I change, depending on the content. Both are not editable (in case that matters).

Currently, I am setting the background with the following command:

```
textArea.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: rgba(255,255,0,.5)");
textField.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: rgba(255,255,0,.5)");
```

While this sets the color correctly, my TextArea still looks a lot brighter than my TextField, which seems to have some sort of shadow/shading going on.

Why is this the case and is it possible to achieve the same look for both?

Comment: I'm tempted to say that it's because of some darker shades that are done in layers in the border/background. The smaller size in `TextField` might make it look darker. It's just my guess, though.

Comment: Hm. This seems to be correct. The shade (that I don't want) depends on `-fx-background-color` - but it seems like the border (that I still want) also depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague managed to solve it with the following lines of code for the TextField:

```
-fx-background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.5); 
-fx-border-color: derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%);
-fx-border-radius: 2;
```

Turns out one should use `-fx-background-color` for **TextFields** and `-fx-control-inner-background` for **TextAreas**. The more you know.